# Download From Web Server

Tags: download, webserver

I want people to be able to download an .png image from my web server, with little success. Whenever I try it just shows the image in my browser

Comment: better tell us why you want to do this, may be we can give you better solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm an IDIOT!
I was doing it right, its just that chrome simply displays png files. When I did Link Text it downloaded. THNX!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you'll need to store that PNG on your webserver. Upload it by ftp, ssh, or some web interface your hosting company has.
Afterwards, put a link in your website to this PNG.

```
<a href="path/to/picture.png">Link Text</a>
```

Notice that the href path should be a relative path to your picture. Meaning that if the web page is stored at the same folder as the picture, you can simply put the picture filename in the href string

Answer (score 0):

You also need to store that image on a publicly accessible folder.

So if your web site is under /var/www/html/mysite/, you'll want to save that png to /var/www/html/mysite/ (or whichever directory you want to store it in).

Answer (score 0):

firstly, it depends on what kind of server your page is running on, and how you serve the static files.

this should give you the general clue:

```
<a href="folder/of/pics/picture.png">download here</a>
```

the correctness of giving the folder hiearchy decides if your foto is downloadable or not..